# ASP.NET core RazorPages - No executable found matching command "dotnet-bundle"

Tags: asp.net, razor, visual-studio-2017, bundling-and-minification

I know - can see related questions for ASP.NET MVC projects & talk around project.json files but i'm using the default project with ASP.NET core with Razor pages & all i believe the equivalent file to edit is the *.csproj file - I've seen a few of the answers do relate to the *.csproj file & i have followed them with still no joy :/  Being new i can't add comments to those answers directly so thought a new post best..

Using VS-2017. Basic project created via /.NET Core/ASP.NET Core Web Application/"Web Application" (just in case i'm leading anyone astray) and with a single test edits made to site.css to test minification.

via NuGet package manager window confirmed BundlerMinifier.Core v2.6.362 is installed

.csproj file contents:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.6.362" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.6.362" />  
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Project saved and built.

When running "dotnet bundle" in the Package Manager Console i get result:

```
PM> dotnet bundle
dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-bundle"
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet bundle
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (No executable f..."dotnet-bundle":String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PM>
```

i honestly have not further clue why this isn't working!??

Ideally all i want to do is incorporate custom css & js into the project, i'm led to believe this is the 'proper' way.. maybe there is a better (i.e. simpler) solution? No idea why this isnt part of the default template, assuming that the template is meant for beginners?..

THANKS!

Comment: And reason for the minus 1?

Comment: i think its a valid question, its supposed to work according to the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x

Comment: Yes this was reproduced on a vanilla VS install

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid problem.

The root is that for some reason the executing directory is not set to the same as what you have selected in VS as the default project.

Try entering `dir` in package manager console. If you are not in your project directory, `cd` into your project and run `dotnet bundle` again.